# Weird glColor3f results in framebuffer objects

Tags: opengl, color, frame-buffer

The code is

```
glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
gluSphere(gluq, 0.2, 10, 10);

glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
glTranslatef(1, 0, 0);
gluSphere(gluq, 0.2, 10, 10);
```

In short, when I draw directly to screen, it's correct.

[image]

But when I create a framebuffer object, attach a texture as color component, draw on the fbo, then draw the texture as rectangle on to the screen, the colors went wrong

[image]

It seems like the right sphere at (1,0,0) changed the color of the sphere drawn before it.

And even more bizzare is that if i change the first sphere's color to blue (0,0,1), it becomes black after the second sphere is drawn.

[image]

The way I rendered it is like this :

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo[0]);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
{
    glViewport(0, 0, SCRWIDTH, SCRHEIGHT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); glLoadIdentity(); gluPerspective(45, (float)SCRWIDTH / (float)SCRHEIGHT, 0.0f, 100.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); glLoadIdentity(); gluLookAt(0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);


    glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
    gluSphere(gluq, 0.2, 10, 10);

    glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
    glTranslatef(1, 0, 0);
    gluSphere(gluq, 0.2, 10, 10);

}
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_tex[0]);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); glLoadIdentity(); glOrtho(0, SCRWIDTH, SCRHEIGHT, 0, -1, 1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); glLoadIdentity();
{
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3i(0, 0, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3i(0, SCRHEIGHT, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3i(SCRWIDTH, SCRHEIGHT, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3i(SCRWIDTH, 0, 0);
    glEnd();
}
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

And I created the fbo and texture like this :

```
glGenTextures(1, &fbo_tex[0]);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_tex[0]);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, SCRWIDTH, SCRHEIGHT, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo[0]);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo[0]);
glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, fbo_tex[0], 0);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

If feels like that consequtive glColor3f caused the colors to mix, taking the minimum RGB values of previous used colors. So white becomes red, but blue turns to black. And the first sphere has the color written to the texture, then the second sphere somehow picks the mixed color and overwrite the first one's pixels. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try calling glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) before calling gluSphere(...)

Comment: Intuitive guess from looking at the images: Looks like you only get or show the red channel. Try to set the white color to grey and see if it turns up dark red.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the colour back to white before drawing the framebuffer to the screen. Otherwise, the whole framebuffer gets multiplied with red.

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

glColor3f(1, 1, 1); // <------- add this (doesn't have to be exactly here)

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_tex[0]);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); glLoadIdentity(); glOrtho(0, SCRWIDTH, SCRHEIGHT, 0, -1, 1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); glLoadIdentity();
{
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3i(0, 0, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3i(0, SCRHEIGHT, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3i(SCRWIDTH, SCRHEIGHT, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3i(SCRWIDTH, 0, 0);
    glEnd();
}
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

Comment: Or even better, change the texture environment to `GL_REPLACE` rather than `GL_MODULATE`, if that is really the problem. (Provided entirely doing away with this legacy fixed function stuff is out of the question already.)

Comment: @ChristianRau Why is that better?

Comment: Because that's the actual problem and a more dirtect solution. You don't *want* to combine your texture's color with a constant color in this scenario anyway. So rather than setting the constant to 1, changing the texture to actually *not* combine with the color feels like the more natural solution to the problem. (If anything, though, it might at least be good to add to the answer that *that*, the texture environment, is the actual cause of the problem, if it is.)

Comment: @ChristianRau I'd wager that most fixed-function apps draw un-colour-modulated textures by using GL_MODULATE and a white colour. That is natural because it's the default.